# video on a plane not playing

Tags: video

I can't seem to get a video on a plane in my project to play.  The first frame shows correctly keyed and in place, but it just stays on the first frame and never plays when I move through the timeline.  I rendered the scene at several points to make sure the refresh might have been slow or non existent, but every render has the first frame in it no matter where on the time line I rendered.  I opened a new project and tried there and the same thing happens.  I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the material for your plane?